# UTF-8で保存したバッチファイルを実行すると文字列がコマンドとして認識されてしまう

Tags: batch-file, 文字コード

お世話になります。

Windows10で、以下のようなコマンドを書いたテキストファイルを、「comand.bat」としてUTF-8形式で保存しました。

```
echo off
chcp 65001
echo スタート：新宿
echo ↓
echo ゴール：東京
pause
```

このcomand.batファイルをダブルクリックして実行すると、「スタート：新宿」という文字列は正しく表示されますが、「ゴール：東京」という文字列が以下のようにコマンドと認識されてしまいます。

```
'��：東京' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

どうしてコマンドとして認識されてしまうのか教えてください。

補足：
「echo ↓」を行わなければコマンドとして認識されないことを確認しています。
また、「echo ↓ 」のように、矢印の後に半角スペースを入れることでコマンドとして認識されなくなることも確認しています。
しかし、なぜこのようになるのかがわかりません・・・

補足2：
cubickさんからのコメントを受けて、文字列をダブルクォートでくくってみたところ、正常に表示されました。
ただし、echoされる文にはダブルクォートが表示されます。（以下、表示例）

```
"スタート：新宿"
"↓"
"ゴール：東京"
```

Comment: 文字列をダブルクォートでくくるとどうなりますか？

Comment: ダブルクォートでくくった結果、文字列として表示できました。本文に補足2として追加しました。

Comment: おそらくwindowsのバグもしくは何らかの仕様じゃないかと思いますが、echo ↓の後の文字をコマンドと認識しているようです。とりあえず↓のあとに半角スペースで対応するしかないかと思います。

Comment: そもそもWindowsはUTF-8を認めておらず、Shift-JISで解釈してから実行していると思います。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

おそらく、コマンドプロンプトはすでにシフトJISとしてバッチファイル全体を読んでおり、バッチファイルの中でコードページを切り替えても手遅れなのでしょう。バッチファイルを起動する前にコードページを切り替えると動くかもしれません。

「↓」を UTF-8 でエンコードすると E2 86 93 です。E2 がシフトJISの第一バイトなので、86は第二バイトとして処理され、93 もシフトJISの第一バイトなので、続く改行コードが第二バイトとして処理されてしまったのだと思います。

Comment: sayuriさんからもコメントで指摘がありましたが、「シフトJISとしてバッチファイル全体を読んで」いるのが今回の原因と思いました。試しに、同じ「E2」から始まる「｜」を使ったところ再現しました。（これといった資料が見つからないのがつらいとこですが・・・）

Comment: @mekaeru UTF-8形式を受け入れるという資料がないのであれば対応していないということでしょう。コントロールパネルには「Unicode対応でないプログラムの言語」という設定があり、そこを日本語（Shift-JIS）が設定されているためにShift-JISは認識されますをその設定をUTF-8に変更すれば動作するかもしれませんが、副作用が大きいのでお勧めはしません。

Answer (score 0):

おそらく改行コードがLFになっているためだと思います。CRLFであれば問題ないようです。
調査された方がいました。
[miauのブログ - 改行コード LF で日本語を含むバッチファイルの動作がおかしい件](https://miau.hatenablog.com/entry/20100929/1285768041)

Comment: 私の環境で確認してみましたが、CR+LFでも問題は解消しませんでした。

Comment: こちらでも確認しましたが、改行コードは「CR+LF」になっていました。また、改行コードを「LF」にした場合はそもそもコマンドが実行できませんでした。